# Правильная ли практика хранить в базе данных html code?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Есть PHP Laravel проект где в базе данных хранится и выводится  html код, общепринятая ли это практика или пример плохого кода, можно ли без этого обойтись и зачем так делают ?

Comment: единственное что приходит в голову зачем это может понадобится - это если в базу сохраняются статьи из визуального редактора. в остальном шаблонизаторы справляются

Comment: вопрос довольно общий(понял, пока писал ответ).. html бывает разный - это может быть: статья, о вреде курения в блог(cms-way), шаблон datepicker, целые страницы `/about`, `/contacts`.. Стоило, наверное, уточнить, о какого рода html-коде идёт речь..

Comment: Если пользователи могут добавлять html, то было бы разумно его очистить как минимум от скриптов например

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### общая информация

Код в базе хранят если это конструктор, шаблон или редактор, хотя для продвинутых редакторов код трансформируется в json или подобные структуры

Если пользователям нужно предоставить возможность форматировать вывод, то сохранять код в базе самое простое решение.

**HTML-код для базы - это просто строка**, никакой опасности нет, при правильном сохранении/санитизации данных.

Опасность - отображение этого кода на странице в браузере пользователя.

### рекомендации

Если вы создаете закрытую систему, для доверенных пользователей, то проблем нет.

Если это открытая система, то однозначно нужно ограничить пользователей базовыми возможностями. Без модерации всё равно не обойтись.

### размышления

Не все задачи, связанные с форматированием контента можно решить через организацию UI. Встроенные HTML-редакторы решают множество проблем для копирайтеров и контент-менеджеров, позволяют создавать и редактировать шаблоны в CMS.  Современная тенденция - это ограничение набора функций с сохранением возможности форматирования.

Answer (score 3):

*В базе нужно хранить данные.

Если ваши данные - это html-код, храните его, в чём проблема?*

---

Основные проблемы хранения html для отображения его в браузере:

- доверие
  Вам придётся доверять пользователям, создающим этот контент. Они без проблем могут внедрить уязвимости в свой html... Если это неопределённый круг лиц — с этим придётся что-то делать.
- статичность
  Эти куски кода верстались под старую версию сайта. Вы обновили дизайн — нужно перепроверять, что все кусочки из базы будут адекватно смотреться в новом дизайне
- производительность
  Статические куски темплейтов лучше таки отдавать с диска напрямую, nginx умеет это делать гораздо шустрее, чем связка php+mysql, а браузеры замечательно их кешируют.

User-generated контент в любом случае стоит как-то ограничивать, современные шаблонизаторы умеют закрывать большинство известных уязвимостей. Используйте один из них и добавьте «Предпросмотр».

Также, вероятно, стоит разбить контент на смысловые составляющие (заголовок, тело и т.п.), чтобы сохранять непосредственно контент(форматирующие шаблоны вроде Markdown/BBcode подойдут) и внедрять уже этот контент в текущий дизайн.

Если же это просто шаблоны для client-side GUI компонентов - перенесите их в document_root. webpack вообще умеет компилировать их в js

---

*Прямо сейчас я набираю этот ответ, и мне достаточно выразительных средств без html. И предпросмотр на месте. Попробуйте пристальнее изучить механизм ввода вопросов/ответов. Если бы stackoverflow хранили бы html, - старые вопросы/ответы сегодня бы выглядели совсем не так, как новые..*